# Dependencies Aren't Loading On Visual Studio For Mac

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, ide

I am new to developing on mac, specifically to target iOS in Xamarin. I have a project which I have built on my PC. It works fine and deploys to my android device fine. Earlier today, I cloned the git repo on my Mac and tried to create an iOS project in Xamarin. I get an error saying none of my dependencies could load. I'm wondering if this is because it's unable to use the DLL's used on PC. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the dependencies as well.

```
2019-03-13 00:02:27.375662-0400 Township.iOS[2052:95863] Could not find `Autofac.Extras.CommonServiceLocator` referenced by assembly `Township.Mobile, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`.
```

2019-03-13 00:02:27.377846-0400 Township.iOS[2052:95863] Could not find `CommonServiceLocator` referenced by assembly `Township.Mobile, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`.
2019-03-13 00:02:27.380663-0400 Township.iOS[2052:95863] Could not find `Newtonsoft.Json` referenced by assembly `Township.Api, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`.
2019-03-13 00:02:27.381606-0400 Township.iOS[2052:95863] Could not find `Xamarin.Forms.Maps` referenced by assembly `Township.Mobile, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`.
2019-03-13 00:02:27.823469-0400 Township.iOS[2052:95863] SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22 cs_flags=200, pid=2052
2019-03-13 00:02:27.823728-0400 Township.iOS[2052:95863] SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: Township.iOS[2052]/0#-1 LF=0
[image: Error 1]
[image: Error 2]

Comment: This question requires psychic debugging.Do you clean your project then to rebuild it?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I'm not sure what you mean by 'psychic debugging' and yes, I've cleaned and rebuilt it.

Comment: Suggest that reInstalling NuGet Package in your project to check it.

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Sorry, didn't get to this until now. Installing the NuGet packages on the Mac did it. I didn't realize the NuGet packages on my PC were stored in a folder not located in the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Can I update this for answer ,then this question can be closed ^.^ @AcePilot10

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Sure, thanks

Comment: Okey,I have posted answer.Thanks in advance for marking it ! @AcePilot10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a project which I have built on my PC. It works fine and deploys to my android device fine. Earlier today, I cloned the git repo on my Mac and tried to create an iOS project in Xamarin. I get an error saying none of my dependencies could load.

The forms project created on the vs. of the PC, when you transfer them to a mac or other PC, you need to check the **NuGet package** of the project. Because the installation of the NuGet package does not follow the project, they just link the NuGet path in the PC to the project, so when you are on a new computer, you need to reinstall the NuGet package.

**Solution：**

Suggest that reInstalling NuGet Package in your project to check it.